# NHibernate query deadlock in case multiple connection

Tags: sql-server-2008, nhibernate, deadlock

I have next transaction:

```
  Desc d = new Desc();
  d.Descr = "new";

  _sess.Transaction.Begin();

  _sess.SaveOrUpdate(d);

  var desc = _sess.CreateCriteria(typeof(Desc)).List<Desc>();

  _sess.Transaction.Commit();
```

This transaction performs next query:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT

SELECT 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

When I perform this code in two processes I have deadlock, because

1 Process

Perform INSERT and lock Key

2 Process

Perform INSERT and lock key

1 Process  wants to perform SELECT and passes in TIMEOUT STATE
2 Process wants to perform SELECT and passes in TIMEOUT STATE

result: deadlock

BD: MS SQL Server 2008 R2

2 questions:

1. How do me set UPDATE LOCK on All tables what included in transaction
2. If I use this code:

   Desc d = new Desc();
     d.Descr = "new";

   _sess.Transaction.Begin(IsolationLevel.Serializable);

   _sess.SaveOrUpdate(d);

   var desc = _sess.CreateCriteria(typeof(Desc)).List();

   _sess.Transaction.Commit();

Nothing changes.

What does IsolationLevel.Serializable do ?

**UPDATE:**

I need to get following:

```
USE Test

BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM [Desc] (UPDLOCK)

INSERT INTO [Desc] (Descr) VALUES ('33333')

SELECT * FROM [Desc] 

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

How do me perform with help NHibernate following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM [Desc] (UPDLOCK)
```

?

Comment: Why is your var desc = _sess.CreateCriteria(typeof(Desc)).List(); included in the transaction? I doesn't make sense to me... It can only cause trouble.

Comment: This is only simple example. Transaction is more complicated in life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change the transaction [isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) to snapshot. This avoids locks when reading data, allows much more concurrency and particularly no deadlocks in read-only transactions.

The reason for the deadlock is following: insert do not conflict with each other. They lock the newly inserted row. The query however is locked out, because it tries to read the newly inserted row from the other transaction. So you get two queries both waiting for the other transaction to complete, which is a deadlock. With isolation level snapshot, the query doesn't care about non committed row at all. Instead of waiting for locks to be released, it only "sees" rows that had been committed. This avoids deadlocks in queries.

Comment: Thanks! But if i change the transaction isolation level to snapshot and transaction does rollback, i will get incorrect data, i am right ? This is no very good.

Comment: Huh? Why should you get incorrect data? The reason of having any kind of transaction isolation is that you are not concerned by other transactions, regardless if they will commit or rollback at the end.

Comment: If following steps happened : 1. First transaction does INSERT 2. Second transaction does INSERT 3. First transaction does SELECT * 4. Second transaction does ROLLBACK, in result: First transaction will return row what was removed when second transaction did ROLLBACK. We will get incorrect data.

Comment: No! The first transaction does never see anything that is not committed by anyone else. Again, it is called *isolation*. You are talking about turning off locking at all (aka read uncommitted), which is a very very bad thing.

Comment: But, if i use "Transaction.Begin(IsolationLevel.Snapshot)"  i get exception: "Snapshot isolation transaction failed accessing database 'Test' because snapshot isolation is not allowed in this database. Use ALTER DATABASE to allow snapshot isolation." If i do following: "ALTER DATABASE TEST
SET  READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON", i get situation with incorrect data. Where do I mistake?

Comment: I don't know. You can't get the situation you describe.